# Calculate electromagnetic torque of synchronous motor?

Tags: synchronous-motor

I usually use this formula $$P=Tω=Τ\frac{2π}{60}n$$

where n is revolutions per minute and P is the power depending on the occasion.

Since we have to deal with a synchronous  motor we have to use the synchronous speed Ns. My big problem is what power should I use. I have everything, power input, power output, all the losses. How should I replace P to find the 'electromagnetic' torque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electromagnetic torque is the torque applied to the rotor through the interaction of electromagnetic fields. The power used to calculate it is the mechanical output power plus the mechanical losses. The mechanical losses are bearing friction and aerodynamic drag also known as windage. It is also the input power minus the electrical losses in the stator consisting of copper losses and iron losses. This assumes that the excitation power is considered separately from the input power.